# Post flow execution - Onstatuschange not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-cloud

I am facing issues with flow execution on finish. I created a screen flow which has screen components as well as the DML operations. There are DMLs that happen after screen inputs. On finish flow goes back to starting screen. I have tried flow-finish-behavior = 'NONE' as well but it is also not working. I have tried JS refresh as well and that is not working as well. It seems like flow is not reaching "FINISHED" status. Any help is appreciated.

**

- JS:

**

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { NavigationMixin } from "lightning/navigation";
import {FlowAttributeChangeEvent} from 'lightning/flowSupport';

import LEAD_STATUS from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Lead_Accepted__c';
import LEAD_OUTCOME_STATUS from '@salesforce/schema/Lead.Lead_Outcome_Status__c';

const leadFields = [LEAD_STATUS];

export default class LeadOutcome_ScreenFlow_Component extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement){
    @api recordId;
    @api lead;
    @track LEAD_OPEN;
    @track LEAD_OBJECT;
    @track LEAD_STATUS;
    @track LEAD_RECORD;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId : '$recordId', fields: leadFields}) lead;
    
    get inputVariables() {
        return [
          {
            // Match with the input variable name declared in the flow.
            name: "recordId",
            type: "String",
            // Initial value to send to the flow input.
            value: this.recordId,
          }
        ];
      }

handleStatusChange(event){
        if(event.detail.status === 'FINISHED') {
            if(this.lead.LEAD_OUTCOME_STATUS!='Closed Won'){
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: 'comm__namedPage',
                    attributes: {
                        name: 'Lead_List__c'
                    }
                });
            }else{
                this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                    type: 'standard__recordPage',
                    attributes: {
                        recordId: this.lead.recordId,
                        objectApiName: 'Lead',
                        actionName: 'view'
                    }
                });
            }
        
            
        }
    }
    refreshPage(event){
        if(event.detail.status === 'FINISHED') {
            location.reload();
        }
    }


    get acceptStatus() {
        let status = getFieldValue(this.lead.data, LEAD_STATUS);
        let outcomeStatus = getFieldValue(this.lead.data, LEAD_OUTCOME_STATUS);
        if (status==null && outcomeStatus==null){
            return true;
        }else if (status=='No'){
            return false;
        }
    }

    get refreshPage(){
        location.reload();
    }

    get statusUptoDate(){
        let acceptStatus = getFieldValue(this.lead.data, LEAD_STATUS);
        let outcomeStatus = getFieldValue(this.lead.data, LEAD_OUTCOME_STATUS);
        if (acceptStatus=='Yes' && outcomeStatus==null){
            return true;
        }else if(acceptStatus=='Yes' && outcomeStatus!= null){
            return false;
        }
    }
}

HTML Code:

<template>
    <lightning-card variant="Narrow">
        <template if:true={acceptStatus}>
            <div>
                <lightning-flow flow-api-name="Lead_Acceptance_Status" flow-input-variables={inputVariables} flow-finish-behavior = 'NONE' onstatuschange = {refreshPage}></lightning-flow>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template if:false={acceptStatus}>
            <div>
                
            </div>
        </template>
        <template if:true={statusUptoDate}>
            <div>
                <lightning-flow flow-api-name="Lead_Outcome_Status" flow-input-variables={inputVariables} onstatuschange = {handleStatusChange}></lightning-flow>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template if:false={statusUptoDate}>
            <div>
                
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```